# Is there anyway to return the same data in datatable from 2 different query in c#?

Tags: mysql, sql

I need some help regarding a web application that I am doing. I need to copy the entire data from group A to group B that is in the same database table. However, there will be cases where the data are the same. Here is one example of my database table

```
id   Name   Age  Group  
-----------------------
1    Alpha  11    A 
2    Bravo  12    A

3    Alpha  11    B      
4    Bravo  12    B
5    Delta  11    B
```

From the example above, you can see that **Alpha** and **Bravo** which both have the same exact age and it exist in both Group A & B.

My question is, is it possible to check for any duplicated data that has the same exact name and age found in both group A & B using a query? I would like to find out which data are the same first so that I can delete the duplicated in Group B **ONLY** while keeping the data of **Delta** at the same

I am quite new & clueless to SQL as I do not know any type of SQL that can  check the duplicated data found in both Group A & B

I hope you guys can give me an informative explanation & answer to the issue I faced

Thank You for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find the duplicates IDs of group B, do a inner self-join like this:

```
SELECT tb.id
    FROM YourTable AS ta
    JOIN YourTable AS tb ON ta.name=tb.name AND ta.age=tb.age
    WHERE ta.group='A'
    AND tb.group='B'
```

You can the use this in a delete, which will remove the duplicated records from group B only as required:

```
DELETE YourTable
    WHERE id IN (
        SELECT tb.id
        FROM YourTable AS ta
        JOIN YourTable AS tb ON ta.name=tb.name AND ta.age=tb.age
        WHERE ta.group='A'
        AND tb.group='B')
```

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)

Answer (score 2):

An example in PostgreSQL. With duplicate_id_list you have the ids which are duplicate. You can use this in a delete query to remove all except the first id in the list.

```
SELECT Name,Age,count(id),string_agg(id, ', ') AS duplicate_id_list FROM
yourtable GROUP BY Name,Age having count(*) > 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `group by` with `count` to get all the name-age combinations that exist in multiple groups, e.g:

```
SELECT name, age, COUNT(DISTINCT `group`) AS groups
FROM test
GROUP BY name, age
HAVING groups > 1;
```

Here is the **[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/94c2b2/4/0)**.

Comment: This gets you a "random" IDs of a duplicate record, e.g. is may be one of group A or B. Selecting ungrouped columns without aggregate function is usually a bug and an error depending on version and configuration of MySQL, see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by

Comment: @Lucero thanks for pointing it out. I have updated my answer (removed id) as OP wanted name and age anyway.

Comment: I think the OP wants the IDs of duplicate group B records: "I would like to find out **which data are the same** first so that I can **delete the duplicated in Group B ONLY** while keeping the data of Delta at the same"